# Parse Platform - Retrieve relations in object

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Okay, so I am really quite familiar with Parse and have used most features in daily development. However, now I need to work with some many-to-many relationships and can't seem to get it to work right. I've tried reading several posts on Stack... but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated:

1) 'Projects' class = (main grouping class and project details)
   a) 'projectTasks' is setup as a relation column and points to the Tasks class.

2) 'Tasks' class = (tasks submitted by user and grouped in projects)

3) I want to be able to Query for certain projects, and get the relation data at same time.

```
test: function(){
        console.warn("Running relations test....")
        var deferred = $q.defer()
        var Projects = Parse.Object.extend("Projects");
        var query = new Parse.Query(Projects)
        query.equalTo("objectId",Parse.User.current().id)
        query.include("projectTasks")
        query.find({
            success: function(res){
                console.log(res)
                deferred.resolve(res)
            },
            error: function(e,r){
                console.log(e,r)
                deferred.reject(e)
            }
        })

        return deferred.promise
    },
```

The response I get never returns the actual data from the relation field... just another promise or whatever it is.

[screen shot of response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeGI5.png)

Maybe I'm just going about this all wrong. Any help would be appreciated. I want to store a project, store tasks, and be able to associate tasks to a project and quickly retrieve all the info per project.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do a second query to get the relation data, which is a second async call.

```
test: function(){
    console.warn("Running relations test....")
    var deferred = $q.defer()
    var Projects = Parse.Object.extend("Projects");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Projects)
    query.equalTo("objectId",Parse.User.current().id)
    query.include("projectTasks")
    query.find({
        success: function(res){ // my code just assumes you get an answer.....
            console.log(res)
            res[0].get('projectTasks').query().find().then(tasks => {
               const response = {parent: res, tasks: tasks};
               deferred.resolve(response);
            }

        },
        error: function(e,r){
            console.log(e,r)
            deferred.reject(e)
        }
    })

    return deferred.promise
},
```

if in the real life of this answer, you are getting an array of results, then the client code that is calling this probably wants to handle the second call to get the tasks as it iterates over the projects...